# Throwing Objects in Unity Using Vive

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, htc-vive

I am trying to use the HTC Vive controller to pick up and throw objects in Unity. The idea is that you get the controller close enough to the object to touch it, hold the trigger to pick it up, and release the trigger while making a throwing motion to throw it. I have a script and box collider on the controller, and rigidbodies and box colliders on the objects. If I try to pick up an object, it kind of shakes and bounces, but uncontrollably. I am also having the issue where the objects bounce around randomly in the environment instead of being still. Any suggestions?

Comment: Throwing objects using HTC Vive in Unity is the "hello world" or a programming language. Please, make some research, you will find plenty of tutorials on the web. Even the demo scenes of the HTC Vive plugins propose this kind of interaction.

Comment: I followed a tutorial. Several, actually. And I am still having issues. Which is why I am here.

Comment: Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: If you don't post code on a programming Q&A site, you're going to have a bad time.

Answer (score -1):

Check this Tutorials. It's good, a bit old but for sure will get you on track and show you how it's done.

[Video Tutorial  - Click me](https://www.raywenderlich.com/149239/htc-vive-tutorial-unity)